# Pesquisar botão através do Content e filtrar na pesquisa

Tags: c#, wpf

Gostaria de implementar um campo de busca, e ele filtrar os botões e mostrar somente os filtrados, neste meu caso meus botoes estão dentro de um `UniformGrid`. Esta função de pesquisa é semelhante ao Search do Windos 8. Preciso em WPF.

Deem uma olhada na imagem.
[image: exemplo campo de busca em WinRT]

Comment: Colocar o codigo fonte de como esta atras dessa tela ajudaria bastante.

Comment: consegui amigo! vlw! Se precisar..

Comment: Coloca a response de como você conseguiu

Comment: O que eu fiz foi renderizar novamente os botoes, passando apenas a colecao dos itens que eu ja tinha em memoria.